# While Loop Condition C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

What does this condition mean in a while loop?

```
 int x;
 cin >> x;
 while(x) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Should probably be `while(cin >> x){`, but cannot tell from such narrow context given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` has an implicit conversion to `bool`. Basically `0` converts to `false`, all nonzero values convert to `true`

So more verbosely, your condition would read

```
while (x != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CoryKramer says, when you have a condition which only contains a variable, even if is a char, int, float, etc. the value 0 is considered as false, and any other as true. If you are using pointers is the same: the NULL value is considered as false, and any other direction is considered as true.